# selecting columns into a list of records with java.util.stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

From a `List<record>`

```
public final class Record {
   ... // Several fields
   private final SimpleSetProperty<String>  _outOfDate;

   Record( ..., SortedSet< String > outOfDate, ... ) {
      ...
      _outOfDate =
         new SimpleSetProperty<>( FXCollections.observableSet( outOfDate ));
      ...
   }

   public SimpleSetProperty<String> outOfDateProperty() {
      return _outOfDate;
   }
   ... // Other accessors
}
```

I'm trying to extract only the `OutOfDate` column (a Set of String) and merging all values into a single Set of String with the following code.

```
List< Record > statuses = worker.getData()._status;
final Set<String> result =
   statuses
      .stream()
      .flatMap(
         r -> r.outOfDateProperty().get().stream())
      .collect( Collectors.toSet());
System.err.println( result );
```

Output:

> class java.util.HashSet: [HF_SYNTHETIZER_1, POWER_METER,
>   SERIAL_SERVER, BENCH_ETH_SW, CW_SENSOR, LF_GENERATOR,
>   SPECTRUM_ANALYZER, PC_SUPERVISION]

It works but it's a bit complicated, no?

My question is : **propose a more concise / readable code**

Comment: I don't think you can do much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out most Stream-related operations and just add all elements to a Set directly using the addAll method of Collection:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(); // or another kind of Set
statuses.forEach(r -> result.addAll(r.outOfDateProperty().get()));
```

It doesn't make much use of the Stream API but, it's a lot shorter and easier to read.